# How access Realm Mobile Platform from Node.js client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, ubuntu, realm

I am running [Realm Mobile Platform](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/) on [Ubuntu Server 16.04.2](https://www.ubuntu.com/server) virtual machine and I am able to access the HTML admin panel and connect to the server using [Realm OS X browser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/realm-browser/id1007457278?mt=12).

On the server, would be possible to install [NPM realm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/realm) an connect to the local database as admin user?

I tried calling `Realm.Sync.User.login` from Node.js console, but I am get an error informing that `Realm.Sync` is not available at developer edition.

Comment: NodeJS-based server-side access to ROS is part of the [Professional edition](https://realm.io/pricing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the node.js Realm SDK with sync is limited to the professional edition. If you would like to use the node SDK with sync you can either get a free trial or install it on an OSX machine.